# How to iterate a xml file with XmlReader class

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader

my xml stored in xml file which look like as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<metroStyleManager>
  <Style>Blue</Style>
  <Theme>Dark</Theme>
  <Owner>CSRAssistant.Form1, Text: CSR Assistant</Owner>
  <Site>System.ComponentModel.Container+Site</Site>
  <Container>System.ComponentModel.Container</Container>
</metroStyleManager>
```

this way i am iterating but some glitch is there

```
 XmlReader rdr = XmlReader.Create(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExecutablePath) + @"\Products.xml");
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                if (rdr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                {
                    string xx1= rdr.LocalName;
                    string xx = rdr.Value;
                }
            }
```

it is always getting empty `string xx = rdr.Value;`
when element is `style` then value should be `Blue` as in the file but i am getting always empty....can u say why?

another requirement is i want to iterate always within `<metroStyleManager></metroStyleManager>`

can anyone help for the above two points. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Blue` is the value of `Text` node, not of `Element` node. You either need to add another if to get value of text nodes, or you can read inner xml of current element node:

```
rdr.MoveToContent();

while (rdr.Read())
{
    if (rdr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
    {                    
        string name = rdr.LocalName;
        string value = rdr.ReadInnerXml();
    }
}
```

You can also use Linq to Xml to get names and values of root children:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(path_to_xml);
var query = from e in xdoc.Root.Elements()
            select new {
               e.Name.LocalName,
               Value = (string)e
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`XmlDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class for this.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument.Load(filename);
foreach (XmlNode node in doc.ChildNodes)
{
    if (node.ElementName == "metroStyleManager")
    {
        foreach (XmlNode subNode in node.ChildNodes)
        {
            string key = subNode.LocalName; // Style, Theme, etc.
            string value = subNode.Value; // Blue, Dark, etc.
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can user XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(strFilePath) to load XML file.

then you can use

```
foreach (XElement xeNode in xDoc.Element("metroStyleManager").Elements())
{
    //Check if node exist
    if (!xeNode.Elements("Style").Any()

    //If yes then
    xeNode.Value
}
```

Hope it Helps...

BTW, its from ***System.XML.Linq.XDocument***